# Add and remove elements constantly from an array by check/uncheck in angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I've faced a problem in angular2, I have 4 checkboxes (`md-checkbox`) here they are :
[image]

here is their `HTML` :

```
<div class="show-orders">
  <md-checkbox [checked]="true" (click)="showOpenOrders(isOpen)">
    <span class="show-orders-label">{{'open' | translate}}</span>
  </md-checkbox>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <md-checkbox [checked]="true" (click)="showInProgOrders(isInProg)">
    <span class="show-orders-label">{{'in_progress' | translate}}</span>
  </md-checkbox>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <md-checkbox (click)="showCompletedOrders(isCompleted)">{{completedStatus}}
    <span class="show-orders-label">{{'completed' | translate}}</span>
  </md-checkbox>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <md-checkbox (click)="showCancelledOrders(isCancelled)">
    <span class="show-orders-label">{{'cancelled' | translate}}</span>
  </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

and here is their simple function implementation in the `TS` file

```
showOpenOrders(isOpen: boolean) {
    if (isOpen) {
    console.log('open');
    }
    this.isOpen = !isOpen;
  }

  showInProgOrders(isInProg: boolean) {
    if (isInProg) {
      console.log('in prog');
    }
    this.isInProg = !isInProg;
  }

  showCompletedOrders(isCompleted: boolean) {
    if (!isCompleted) {
      console.log('completed');
    }
    this.isCompleted = !isCompleted;
  }

  showCancelledOrders(isCancelled: boolean) {
    if (!isCancelled) {
      console.log('cancelled');
    }
    this.isCancelled = !isCancelled;
  }
```

As you can see I have two checkboxes that are checked by default,
what I want is that I have a default `array` of strings:

> `status: string[ ]= ['open','in_progress','','']`

I want that with every `click` on every checkbox , a string will be added to the array constantly or removed from it , depending on the status of the `checkbox` whether it is **checked** or **not** , am not requesting a full solution , some guidance with `TypeScript` and HTML5 will be enough ,Thank you in advance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the same place that you call console.log you can call a function that add or remove the string from the list, something like:

```
private addOption(option){
   this.status.push(option);
}

private removeOption(option){
   this.status = this.status.filter(_option => _options != option)
}
```

and in your click functions you can do something like this:

```
showInProgOrders(isInProg: boolean) {
    if (isInProg) {
        ...
        this.addOption('in_progress');
    } else {
        this.removeOption('in_progress');
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You're just awesome :) , although i did not try it but seems good way , Thank you ..